# merge 3 tables in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access

I need to merge data from 3 tables across 2 databases in ASP.Net using Access 2007.

`tableA` resides in one database, `tableB` and `tableC` in another, all are on the same server.

My 'Select' statement runs as follows:

```
Select * from tableA
inner join myfilepathname.tableB on tableA.column1 = tableB.column2
inner join myfilepathname.tableC on tableB.column2 = tableC.column3
```

`tableA` doesn't have a data field related to `tableC` which is why I'm using the joint to `tableB` to bring the 3 sets of data together.

I keep getting the error message:

```
'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 
  'tableA.column1 = tableB.column2 INNER JOIN 
   myfilepathname.tableC on tableB.column2 = tableC.column3'
```

Can anyone help with where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you setting links to tables and using Access query builder to help construct the SQL?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for the web project.  The built-in query builder won't let me get past 'inner join' so I'm creating the script freehand.

Comment: Why do you have myfilepathname.tableB in your table declaration? It should only be tableB.

Comment: tableB and tableC are in a different database file to tableA as explained in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding brackets to your query. In Access multiple joins look like below:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ((origintable
JOIN jointable1 ON ...)
JOIN jointable2 ON ...)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, adding the brackets around the join sections of the query fixed it immediately!  Thank you!

Comment: A supplementary question - I need multiple 'AND' conditions in the search which now looks like this:

Comment: `SELECT ...
FROM ((origintable
JOIN jointable1 ON ...AND....AND)
JOIN jointable2 ON ...AND...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Select * from tableA 
inner join tableB on tableA.column1 = tableB.column2 
inner join tableC on tableB.column2 = tableC.column3
```